# Matrix Sparsity Pattern

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sparse-matrices, sparsity

Suppose I have a matrix $H^{+} = (H^T H)^{-1} H^T$ where $H$ is a sparse matrix. Consider the case where only the sparsity pattern i.e. the zero elements of $H^{+}$ matrix is known, then would it be possible to infer the sparsity pattern or any other information of the $H$ matrix in either a deterministic or a probabilistic sense?  Is there any reference or textbook that discusses such problems?